# Were would the appropriate location to store files in a website? Like a temp file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application that downloads a file and then has to unzip it and use the data.

Where would the correct location be to store this file?

If I were using a windows Forms application I would store it in the bin and use the following to get the path. I'm trying to do the same for a web application?

```
String path = Application.StartupPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in the root of your project and call it 'Temp' or something similar.
Store the downloaded files in it.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best place would be to create a folder outside the root folder of the application so that this folder won't be accessible by website users.

To access this folder you have mainly two options:

1. create a virtual directory on the IIS level and access it.
2. Use AspEnableParentPaths, here is an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524697%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: It is a good thing to store files outside of the webapplication, it is NOT a good thing to then create an virtual folder in IIS, this will drag the file back in your webapplication with all the associated security issues